# Cmder seems to be broken after git push, how can I fix the clink.lua?

Tags: laravel, git, lua, cmder, laragon

I'm working in a group using GitHub, and when I tried transferring my work to the remote repo it didn't allow me to. It says I must do `git pull` first, so I did. That created some conflict in my code, then I tried to do `git push` again and that didn't work either.

So I switched to a new branch and tried to push from there. Didn't work with a simple `git push`, but  a similar instruction worked for me.

Since then cmder keeps showing this:

```
    C:\laragon\bin\cmder\vendor/clink.lua:219: attempt to index local 'HEAD' (a nil value)
    C:\laragon\www\pharmacie>
```

Which allows me only to use instructions like `php artisan serve`, but not Git instructions like `git status`...

I already tried some clink.lua code that I found on github, but didn't work.

I tried abandoning my project, so I cloned the remote repo locally.

But then it didn't clone the vendor folder or the `.env` file; so I added them from an other repo (so it could compile) and changed the DB name in the `.env` file to match my project. 
Now it keeps giving an error that says the table of the project I got vendor + `.env` from doesn't exist. But I didn't leave that table in the `.env`, I changed it to my project.
Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO, we are really happy to help newcomers here but I found very difficult to understand what is your question. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably due to a conflict in a file you didn't handle.

When there is a conflict, a file usually looks like this:

```
<<<<<<<<< HEAD

// Some code

==============

// Some other code

>>>>>>>>> branch
```

And you have to choose what you want to save and what you want to delete after the merge.

So I would recommend to you to check your `C:\laragon\bin\cmder\vendor/clink.lua` file at line 219 to see if it could contain what I just said above.

And by the way, you should add your `vendor` folder in your `.gitignore`

And for the problem with your .env file, did you run `php artisan migrate` ?

**EDIT**

And because the problem come from your `vendor` folder, you could resolve it by deleting your `vendor` folder and run `composer install` to reinstall your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue. I resolve the issue by updating the cmder.

[image]

As like the image above for that click on the upper right corner (Setting) on the cmder window.

```
1. Choose:     General -> Update
2. Check the Startup checkbox for (Do automatic check on) and then 
3. Click the save settings button
4. Restart the cmder. 
5. It will prompt for update and allow it to update.
6. Restart cmder again and it will resolve the issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

I repair it as follows:

1. clone the repository again into another folder
2. access the hidden .git folder and copy only the folders (hooks, info, logs ...), do not copy the files
3. replace the folders in the .bin folder of the newly cloned project with the old one

with this I recover the branches and the code of my project, I hope and it will be useful to someone.